# Find all the parameter values for which the series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I need to find all the values of $a$ for which the series beneath converges.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\tan\frac{1}{k}-1}\right)^a\ \ \ (*)
$$
I did the following:
$$
e^{\tan\frac{1}{k}-1}\sim e^{\frac{1}{k}-1}\sim \left(\frac{1}{k}-1\right)+1=\frac{1}{k}\Rightarrow\\
(*)\ \text{converges} \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^a} \text{converges} \Rightarrow\\
(*)\ \text{converges} \iff a > 1
$$
Have I done everything correctly?

Comment: Maybe the series should be $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\tan\frac{1}{k}}-1\right)^a$$ Can you check that?

Comment: No, it is definitely the way I have written it.

Comment: Ok, just in case for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\tan\frac{1}{k}}-1\right)^a$ we can use limit comparison test since 


$$\frac{\left(e^{\tan\frac{1}{k}}-1\right)^a}{\frac1{k^a}} \to 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\left(e^{\tan\frac{1}{k}-1}\right)^a \to \frac 1{e^a}$$

then the series can't converge.

Comment: Well, I get it. Thank you! But why can't we use equivalent functions like I did?

Comment: @Bonrey You expansion is not correct.

Comment: @Bonrey We have $\tan x=x+O(x^3) \implies e^{\tan x-1}\sim \frac1e (1+x)$.

Comment: I got this, thank you!